# How can I reduce the number of function calls in my code?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

Consider the code shown below. I was expecting `e1[x1_, x2_, x3_]` to be called same number of times as `g1[x1_, x2_, x3_]`, but it is called more often.
(Before running this code turn on Debugger mode)
Is there a way to reduce number of times that a function is being called?

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]]; 
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]; 
CleanSlate[]; 
ClearInOut[];  

e1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := Cross[{x1, x3, x2}, {1, x2, x1}];  

f1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := 0 /; x1 == 0 && x2 == 0; 
f1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := e1[x1, x2, x3][[2]]/e1[x1, x2, x3][[3]];  

g1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := {0, f1[x1, x2, x3], f1[x1, x2, x3]^2};  

h1[(x1_)?NumericQ, (x2_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g1[x1, x2, x3][[2]], {x3, 0, 1}];  

RuntimeTools`Profile[Plot[h1[t^2, t], {t, 1, 2*Pi}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Since e1 enters into f1 twice, which in turn enters g1 twice, your obtain a factor of 8, when compared to g1. Hope, you can obtain some speedup if you force e1 to remember its value: e1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := e1[x1,x2,x3]=Cross[{x1, x3, x2}, {1, x2, x1}];  Unfortunately it can start to eat memory in a longer run.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to mention that the Debugger in the Evaluation menu has to be switched on in order for the profiling to work. 
Programmatically this can be done by `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  "DebuggerSettingsDebuggerEnabled"] = True`

Comment: Take a look at memoization, which speeds up repeated calls of expensive functions as mentioned by @user18792 :https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not evaluate `e1` and `g` only once in your function definitions:

```
e1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := Cross[{x1, x3, x2}, {1, x2, x1}]
f1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := With[{e = e1[x1, x2, x3]}, e[[2]]/e[[3]]]
g1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := With[{f = f1[x1, x2, x3]}, {0, f, f^2}]
h1[(x1_)?NumericQ, (x2_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g1[x1, x2, x3][[2]], {x3, 0, 1}];
```

Then:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],"DebuggerSettingsDebuggerEnabled"]  =True;
RuntimeTools`Profile[Plot[h1[t^2,t],{t,1,2*Pi}]];
```

produces the profile:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the number of function calls by using `PlotPoints`:

```
RuntimeTools`Profile[Plot[h1[t^2, t], {t, 1, 2*Pi}, PlotPoints -> 10]]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Sorry that i didn't convey my question properly. I was actually trying to reduce the number of times the function  e1[x1,x2,x3] is being called. I found "user18792" approach to be more general solution to my problem. Thank for the help.